# CSS Sticky doesn't move in a relative way

Tags: html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_relative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #two
        {
            color: red;
            top:   5px;
            left:  5px;
            position: relative;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "parent">
            <div class = "child"> One </div>
            <div class = "child" id = "two"> Two </div>
            <div class = "child"> Three </div>
        </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This moves `#two` child a bit away, but when I change `relative` to `sticky`, `#two` child doesn't move anywhere.

What is it supposed to do with `sticky`? I thought `sticky` moves like `relative` but sticks at the time of scrolling.

Comment: *I thought sticky moves like relative but sticks at the time of scrolling.* --> you are wrong, this is not how sticky i supposed to work. Read the duplicates to understand sticky

Answer (score -1):

'sticky' use for stick a object(tag) to a place (top, right, left, bottom ,...)